# script to rename all files & directories into lowercase (including unicode)

Tags: windows, powershell, lowercase

(1)
I have about 200 directories, with probably a 1000 sub-directories containing 10,000 of files.

I would like to keep the names intact, but change them all to lower case, including Unicode characters such as 'É' (to 'é').

Can you advise how it could be done through PowerShell? It is my own computer and I have admin rights.

Comment: Isn't Windows case insensitive? I.e. you wouldn't be able to rename file1 to FILE1. The operation would be denied because the OS will see no difference between the two. Check this: https://superuser.com/a/505827/206562

Comment: @marekful that's not correct. While windows works case insensitive (you can call `Test.txt` using `test.txt`), it differs between different capitalized names. `Rename-Item TEST.txt test.TXT` would just rename `TEST.txt` to `test.TXT` and not be denied. Your reference is for file explorer and about 5 Years old.

Comment: hi there, it is for "cosmetic" purposes :) it is much simpler to have all those files and directories in lower case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure most people can write this one but the idea is for you to write it. So we will point in the right direction.

Use [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) with `-Recurse` switch to get all files and folders under a directory.

Use the [`ToLower()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert strings to lowercase.

Use [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1) to rename the folders or directories you want to.

I tried it and it worked for unicode as well. You may need to handle files and folders differently. I had to.

EDIT:
For Files:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object{ Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $_.name.ToLower()}
```

Comment: Here is what I have tried so far: Rename-Item ToLower(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath D:\test -Directory -File -Recurse) not sure the syntax is correct :(

Comment: Tried this and does not work too :( Get-ChildItem D:\test -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name.ToLower() }

Comment: You will need to iterate through each returned items and rename it. sending it to a pipe is not enough. Use foreach-object like i edited the answer above

Comment: I trust you can figure out the one for directories.

Answer (score 1):

The commands that I use to folders and files, I hope it helps.

```
for /r "G:\Teste" %D in (.) do @for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /l/b/ad "%D"') do @ren "%D\%F" "%F"
for /r "G:\teste" %D in (.) do @for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /l/b/a-d "%D"') do @ren "%D\%F" "%F"
```